# How to show username after login in web page

Tags: php, html, css

I created simple web page using php and html...In my page logged in successfully but I dont know how to show username after login.. At the same time i want hide login and signup.. Please anyone help..

Here my code:

```css
.welcome
{
  float:right;
  width:33.33%;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: right;

}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    
   
       <div class="welcome">
   <!--<a href="" id="welcome">Welcome!!</a>-->
   <?php
       
                    if (isset($_SESSION['name1'])) {
                        /*echo ' <div class="rightone" onclick = "arrow();">';
                        echo '<ul>';
                        echo '<li><div class="arrow-down"></div>';
                        echo '<div class="arrow-up"></div>';
                        echo   '<ul>';
                        echo     '<li><div>';
                        echo      '<a  class="h2" href="php/logout.php" >Logout</a>';
                        echo      '</div></li>';
                        echo     '<li><div><a href="php/account.php">Account</a></div></li>';
                        echo     '<li><div><a href="php/resetpassword.php">Reset password</a></div></li>';
                        echo   '</ul>';
                        echo  '</li>';
                        echo '</ul>';*/
                        echo "Hi,";
                        echo $_SESSION['name1'];
                        //echo '</div>';
                    }
                    
                    ?>

   </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Sign Up</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                Please Fill all the fields!

                                <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Name</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Mobile Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="row">
                        
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                Welcome Back!

                                <!--<form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">-->
                                <form class="form" role="form"  action="php/sign.php" method="post" >
                               <?php
                            if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
                                $message = $_GET['msg'];
                                if ($message == 2) {
                                    echo '
              <p>
              <span class="title" style="color:red;">
              *Invalid username or password
              </span>
              </P>
              ';
                                }
                            }

                            ?>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                        <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        

    </div>
</nav>
```

My page:[image]
Thanks for advance!!!

Comment: You need session_start() at the top of any pages that use sessions

Comment: I dont know how to hide that signup and login

Comment: `if(condition){ do something } else{ do something else }` - Learn how to use conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

After login successfully store user details into session.

In html page, check `if($_SESSION[userdetails])` is not available then show the login and signup form.

```
<?php
?>
<html>
<body>
......
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION[user_details])) { ?>
<div>
<!-- login -->
</div>
<div>
<!-- signup -->
</div>
<?php } else { 
echo $_SESSION[user_details][username]; ?>

.......
</body>
</html>
```